# div invisible in IE

Tags: css, html, visibility

I made some div's to make buttons, however some of these div's are invisible in IE. In other browsers this worked perfect, just not in IE. Some people said that it would be enough to just delete the browser cache. I did this, but it had no effect. I don't know what I did wrong. it is about these two div's:

```
    <div id="searchButtons">
        <!--Inside are the buttons, which are div's that are clickable using a hyperlink-->
        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('SearchForm').submit();"><div id="searchButton" class="searchButton" style="width:70;">
            Search
        </div></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('SearchForm').reset();"><div id="resetButton" class="searchButton" style="width:70; left:70;">
            Reset
        </div></a>
    </div>

    <div id="loginButtons">
        <a href="#" onclick="CheckLoginData(2)"><div id="LoginButton" class="loginButton" style="width:60;">
        <!--CheckLoginData(2) is a function, which checks if al inputs are entered, the parameter (2) has to do with the tabs I made in another part of this file-->
            Login
        </div></a>
        <a href="Register.php"><div id="Register" class="loginButton" style="left:60; width:70;">
            Register
        </div></a><br/>
        <a href="ForgotPassword.php" target="_blank">Forgot password</a>
    </div>
```

before the first div, there is a form which is submitted using this div.

The second div contains some buttons that are used to login, register or to go to forgot password page.
These div's have some css:

```
div.loginButton,div.searchButton{
position:absolute;
color:blue;
background-color:FFFF99;
height:20;
transition:background-color 0.2s;
-webkit-transition:background-color 0.2s,transform 0.2s;
}
div.loginButton:hover,div.searchButton:hover{
position:absolute;
background-color:CCCC7A;
height:20;
transition:background-color 0.2s;
-webkit-transition:background-color 0.2s,transform 0.2s;
}
#loginButtons,#searchButtons{
position:absolute;
top:130;
height:25;
left:20;
width:140;
}
```

The strange part is that only the first hyperlink inside each div is invisible. The others are visible. I have tried to use the style attribute display, but it had no effect. I have no clue what I did wrong. Is there any sugestion?

Comment: what ie version are you looking at?

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but it is IE 7 or lower.

Comment: It is working fine for me in IE9

Comment: My computer is very old so I can't use that version. Then my computer would complain.

Comment: Is that code re-typed?  Your values for top, height, left and width don't specify any units, which would make them hard for most browsers to interpret.

It's not likely to be the root cause of your problem, especially in IE7, but it's worth correcting anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plugging that code straight into a blank page the links sit on top of each other due to the absolute positioning. Remove the absolute positioning and all your links should be visible.

Comment: I only put these two div's together like this because the same thing occurs. In the whole website the two div's are in different places. I think that's what you mean... sorry if I'm wrong.

Comment: sorry... I was wrong, it is great that they are both visible, but is there a way to get them next to each other instead of underneath each other?

Comment: Can you apply a float: left to your two divs to get the result you need?